# dynamic putting onchange events using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

i get a array of drawerFields which is dynamic. i am trying to write onchange event for this. but when this onchange event triggers it has not yet resolved dependentName hence remains undefined.

```
function dcdcsCascadeEffect(){
   for(var j=0;j+1<drawerCompleteFields.length;j++){
      var dependentName=drawerCompleteFields[j+1];
      var parentName=drawerCompleteFields[j];
      $('#'+parentName).on('change',function(){
        callFilterDataLoaderFunction(dependentName);
      });
    }
 }

 function callFilterDataLoaderFunction{
    window[filterFields[filterName].type + "FilterOperations"](filterFields[filterName]);
 }
```

HTML :

```
<select data-placeholder="Division" multiple="multiple" class="multiselectFilter" id="divisions" style="width: 100%; display: none;">
 <option value="multiselect-all">All</option>
 <option value="1" selected="">Mobile</option>
</select>
```

Can somebody tell me how to achieve this.

Comment: callFilterDataLoaderFunction? where is this function?, please add some html and the complete javascript to help you :)

Comment: just seeing the title, I guess you may want to find more about ***event delegation*** in jQuery, which can be done with the most modern method `.on()`.

Comment: @user2696466 `on()` has 2 usages, a normal usage is for static event binding, the other usage is for dynamic event binding. You're using the static event binding.

Comment: ah, after looking into your code, I can see that it's not the problem of event delegation, now the problem is ***event data***.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the so-called ***event-data*** can solve your problem:

```
function dcdcsCascadeEffect(){
  for(var j=0;j+1<drawerCompleteFields.length;j++){
    var dependentName=drawerCompleteFields[j+1];
    var parentName=drawerCompleteFields[j];
    $('#'+parentName).on('change', dependentName, function(e){
      callFilterDataLoaderFunction(e.data);
    });
  }
}
```

Reference [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) you can see the syntax right at the beginning:

> .on( events [, selector ] ***[, data ]***, handler )